# Delete items on hand when added to cart with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am building a small e-commerce site out and want to be able to have the stock on hand be updated when items are added or deleted from someone's cart. In my cart controller, I have four functions: one to add an item, one to increase the item, one to decrease the item, and one to remove an item. Here is the code for that:

```
     public function addItemToCart(Request $request, $id) {

    $prevCart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($prevCart);

    $product = Product::find($id);
    $cart->addItem($id, $product);
    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->route("home");

}

public function increaseSingleProduct(Request $request, $id) {

    $prevCart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($prevCart);

    $product = Product::find($id);
    $cart->addItem($id, $product);
    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function decreaseSingleProduct(Request $request, $id) {

    $prevCart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($prevCart);

    if( $cart->items[$id]['quantity'] > 1) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $cart->items[$id]['quantity'] = $cart->items[$id]['quantity']-1;
        $cart->items[$id]['totalSinglePrice'] = $cart->items[$id]['quantity'] * $product['price'];
        $cart->updatePriceAndQunatity();

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function deleteItemFromCart(Request $request, $id) {

    $cart = Session::get('cart');

    if(array_key_exists($id, $cart->items)){
        unset($cart->items[$id]);
    }
    $prevCart = $request->session()->get("cart");
    $updatedCart = new Cart($prevCart);
    $updatedCart->updatePriceAndQunatity();

    $request->session()->put("cart",$updatedCart);

    return redirect()->route('shopping cart'); 
}
```

The quantity here does not refer to the quantity on hand, it refers to the quantity in the cart. In the products table, I have a column that is called stock_quantity. Ideally, this is what I would like to get updated as each function is performed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Drewster how do I get the stock_quantity to be updated when each function is performed. So if some adds 1 of an item to the cart I want that stock quantity to be updated in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be getting the complexity of your question. Don't you just have to find the product and increment or decrement?

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($item_id);
$product->stock_quantity++; // or --
$product->save();
```

I wouldn't be doing this as you add to the cart though. I'd do it on checkout instead so that you don't leave your stock committed with an abandoned cart. Alternatively, if you really need to commit your stock while someone has something in the cart, implement a function to remove the committed stock if it's abandoned.

Comment: I kind of went back and forth on were it should be implemented. But I think you are right adding to to when a customer checks out would probably be best. I’ll give this code a try in my checkout out controller.

Comment: I added this into my checkout controller and I get an error. Would it be helpful to edit the controller code above to reflect that? Or just post a whole new question?

Comment: Disregard that, I tweaked your example slightly and made it work.

Comment: What did you do to make it work? I'll edit the answer so that it's correct in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: @NateScott Please let me know if this answer needs to be updated, otherwise can you please mark it as correct?

Comment: sorry I forgot to reply to you on this. I had to change ($items[id]) tp be ($item_id). If you correct that in your example then it is correct.

Comment: @NateScott Corrected.